# Can I make Windows Explorer Treeview show folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm sure this has been answered a million times around the web, but I dont know quite what question to ask.

Basically before windows 7 if I opened a folder in the right hand pane when using windows explorer the corresponding folder would be expanded in the treeview on the left.

This is no longer happening.  Can I switch it on on Windows 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **Right click** an empty space in the **left panel** and **check** `[x] Expand to current folder` (Thank you, [surfasb](https://superuser.com/users/24500/surfasb)):

  [image: Right click]

### Or...

- **Check** `[x] Automatically expand to current folder` in **Folder Options** > **General** > **Navigation pane**:

  [image: Organize]

  [image: Folder Options]

Comment: Don't sweat it. It's never a bad idea to ask a simple question. Someone might have the same question and end up here. It's handy. :)

Comment: You can also right click an empty area in the TreeView and get the option there.

Comment: @surfasb Added it!

Answer (score 0):

hmmm,

I guess I should have gone looking.

Organise > Folder and Search Options > Automatically Expand to Current Folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you may find useful:

If you want to expand all the folders and subfolders for a particular drive, click on that drive and press the ' * ' key on the numeric keyboard.

To expand individual highlighted folders press '+'

Who knew?? :-)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.